# Why isn't std::set just called std::binary_tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, set, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

std::set in C++ is not a real set in terms of data structures. std::unordered_set is a real set, but std::set is a **binary search tree**, more specifically a red-black tree. Why, then, is it called std::set? Is there some specific functionality that sets a std::set apart from a binary tree? Thanks.

Comment: Because its elements should be sorted.

Comment: it is called set, beceause it is a set ;). Dont really understand why you think it is none. It can be implemented as a binary search tree, but not necessarily.

Comment: it is about the interface you use not about how it is implemented

Comment: @vahancho This is also the case in a binary search tree

Comment: @user463035818 This is the most rational explanation, though I was more curious to know if there was some fundamental difference between an std::set and a binary search tree. Also, I am curious as to why they couldn't just throw the interface onto a BST, as they would all make sense just fine

Comment: maybe one day someone will find a clever different way to implement the requriements of a `std::set` then `std::binary_search_tree` would be the wrong name

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Then how can it be implemented?

Comment: @curiousguy thats a different question. `std::set` can be implemented as a binary tree, but it could be implemented in a different way. For users of `std::set` that should not matter

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 What difference would exist inside the implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why isn't std::set just called std::binary_tree?

Because

1. Tree doesn't describe how the interface is used. Set does.
2. `std::set` does not provide sufficient operations to be used as a general purpose search tree. It only provides an interface to a particular application of a search tree: The representation of a set.
3. Technically the standard doesn't specify that `std::set` is a binary search tree; although red-black BST may be the only data structure that can achieve the requirements imposed on `std::set`, and the interface has carefully been specified with that data structure in mind, the choice of internal data structure is an implementation detail.
4. For same reason `std::unordered_set` isn't called `std::hash_table`.

> std::unordered_set is a real set, but std::set is a binary search tree

`std::unordered_set` isn't any more or less "real" than `std::set` is. They are both sets with slightly different requirements and guarantees; One designed to be implementable using a tree, and another designed to be implementable using a hash table.

P.S. Tree and a hash table are not the only ways to represent a set. One internal data structure that can implement most - but not all - of `std::set` is a sorted vector. Especially for small sets, a sorted vector can be much faster than `std::set`.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understood correctly, this comes down to the standard not specifying that the implementation has to be a red-black tree, and the interface being limited to that of an ordered set.