# Implementation of std::set using different data structures

Tags: c++, set, language-lawyer, std

Inspired by this question: [Why isn't std::set just called std::binary_tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375528/why-isnt-stdset-just-called-stdbinary-tree) I came up with one of my own. Is red-black tree the only possible data structure fullfilling requirements of `std::set` or are there any others? For instance, another self-balancing tree - [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) - seems to be good alternative with very similar properties. Is it theoretically possible to replace underlying data structure of `std::set` or is there a group of requirements that makes red-black tree the only viable choice?

Comment: AVL tree has worse performance (not to be confused with asymptotic complexity) than RB tree in most real world situations. You can use an AVL tree and be compliant, but it will not win you any customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVL trees have worse performance (not to be confused with asymptotic complexity) than RB trees in most real world situations. You can base `std::set` on AVL trees and be fully standard-compliant, but it will not win you any customers.